# Autofill Formula to end of data VBA

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, formula, autofill

When I looked up a VBA to auto-fill a formula to the end of the data on all of my worksheets in a workbook, I found this one:

```
Sub FillFormula()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Range("Q2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2)"
ws.Range("Q2", "Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
Next
End Sub
```

And it works fine, but not with my formula. I need it to work with this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,CHAR(10),"Serving:"," ", O2,CHAR(10),"Contact:"," ", B2," ", C2,CHAR(10), F2, ",", " ", G2, " ",H2,CHAR(10), I2,",", " ", J2, " ",K2,CHAR(10),"Phone:"," ",L2,CHAR(10), "Fax:"," ",M2,CHAR(10), "Email:", " ", D2,CHAR(10),"Website:", " ", N2,CHAR(10),P2,CHAR(10)," ",CHAR(10))
```

However, because of the many " in the formula, it won't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to start that with a quote like `"=CONC...` and triple up on quotes to explicitly add quotes into it `"""`

Comment: Whoops it’s actually double up not triple up

Comment: Why not use CHAR(34)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Marcucciboy2 said, you have to double up your quotation marks inside a formula when using VBA:

```
Sub FillFormula()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Range("Q2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,CHAR(10),""Serving:"","" "", O2,CHAR(10),""Contact:"","" "", B2,"" "", C2,CHAR(10), F2, "","", "" "", G2, "" "",H2,CHAR(10), I2,"","", "" "", J2, "" "",K2,CHAR(10),""Phone:"","" "",L2,CHAR(10), ""Fax:"","" "",M2,CHAR(10), ""Email:"", "" "", D2,CHAR(10),""Website:"", "" "", N2,CHAR(10),P2,CHAR(10),"" "",CHAR(10))"
ws.Range("Q2", "Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
Next
End Sub
```